# Insertion Sort algorithm

Tags: algorithms

What would be the worst case time complexity of insertion sort if its input are restricted to permutations of $1$ to $n$ with atmost $n$ inversions?

In worst case i.e with $n(n-1)/2$ inversions, time complexity is $O(n^2)$. But when the inversions are limited to $n$ then complexity is $O(n)$. How to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of steps taken by insertion sort is $O(n+k)$ where $k$ is the number of inversions. The proof follows by just observing that insertion sort can be implemented using only swaps without changing the time complexity, and that for each of the $n$ passes, every element accessed and compared is followed by a swap except the last, and every swap fixes exactly one inversion. Can you get it now?